# How to implement long-running network uploads in Android not using AsyncTask and not using libraries

Tags: android, android-asynctask

What is the native Android way to implement long running network operations (like uploading a bunch of photos) without having to use libraries like RoboSpice?

*I've read numerous topics on stackoverflow suggesting that asynctask is not suitable for long running operations as it is closely tied to an activity's lifecycle, might lead to memory leaks and since android 3.2 there is only one thread for all asynctasks for an app. (not sure about this last one)*

How do I replace my asynctask with something else?

**Now, I've heard of handlers, executors, services and what not, but how exactly do I implement them in my code and which one to choose?**

Here is an example of the asynctask I use

**I have removed a lot of code, just so you can see the basic structure**

```
public class UploadPhotosToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


        try {
            if(uploadImageToServer(id, path, params)) {
       success = true;
} else {
        success = false;
}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
        }


    return success;
} 

public boolean uploadImageToServer(int imageId, String imagePath, HashMap<String, String> params) throws Exception {

    try {
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.uploadImageToServer(imagePath, params);
        JSONObject message = json.getJSONObject("message");
        String serverResponse = message.getString("success");
        if (serverResponse.contentEquals("true") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

and here is jsonParser.uploadImageToServer

```
public JSONObject uploadImageToServer(String imagePath, HashMap<String, String> params) throws Exception {

        HttpResponse response;
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity;
        HttpPost postRequest;
        HttpContext localContext;
        Bitmap bitmap;

        try {
            // Set the http handlers
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            postRequest = new HttpPost(SERVER + "images");

            // Send the package
            multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(imagePath)));
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                multipartEntity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            postRequest.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
            // Get the response. we will deal with it in onPostExecute.
            response = httpClient.execute(postRequest, localContext);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                json = sb.toString();
                inputStream.close();
                reader.close();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Try parsing the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Return JSON String
            return jsonObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with AsyncTask? It makes the use of threads easy.

Comment: what i suggest to write an an `alarm manager` to invoke a `service` to upload data in background thread using asynctask

Comment: I've read numerous topics on stackoverflow suggesting that asynctask is not suitable for long running operations as it is closely tied to an activity's lifecycle, might lead to memory leaks and since android 3.2 there is only one thread for all asynctasks for an app.

Comment: @NitinMisra can you give me an example code?

Comment: I already have such a service, and a WiFi listener that invokes the upload, but I was wondering what can I use INSTEAD of an asynctask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for a set of uploads I would consider implementing an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). As explained at the link it will process a list of intents in a worker thread until that list is exhausted at which point the service will shutdown again.

The implementation of an `IntentService` is very simple. An example based on the example you give above;

```
public class ImageUploadIntentService extends IntentService {

    public ImageUploadIntentService() {
        super("ImageUploadIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Not a required implementation but you might want to setup any dependencies
        // here that can be reused with each intent that the service is about to
        // receive.

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Process your intent, this presumably will include data such as the local
        // path of the image that you want to upload.
        try {
            uploadImageToServer(intent.getExtra("image_to_upload"), params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oh :( Consider updating any internal state here so we know the state
            // of play for later
        }
    }

    public JSONObject uploadImageToServer(String imagePath, HashMap<String, String> params) throws Exception {
        // All of your upload code
    }

}
```

Then to call the service it is as simple as;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageUploadIntentService.class)
    .putExtra("image_to_upload", mImagePath);
startService(intent);
```

This does leave us with the issue of indicating the progress of your upload queue. We can solve this by using a [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html). A result receiver is `Parcelable` so we can send it with the intent in order to listen out for results we might be interested in. You can handle the `ResultReceiver` with either an `Activity` and suitable piece of progress dialog, or if you want a persistent notification with a progress bar then you could use a `Service` to host the receiver.

It is a little more involved than using an `AsyncTask`, but it does give you a little more flexibility and is not as attached to the Activity lifecycle. Another gotcha with the `IntentService` it will still only make you one worker thread so image uploads could not happen concurrently. But I might consider breaking your Bitmap JPEG compression to it's own `IntentService` then you could have the compression happening on the next image in the queue while the first is being uploaded.

Comment: Thanks I will consider this and give it a try!

Comment: Do I add this service to the Manifest?

Comment: Yep it's just like any other service, so you will need to go ahead and add it to your manifest.